# Getting errorcode 1010 while trying to create app for few servers in mastodon

Tags: mastodon

We try to create mastodon app dynamically, when any user enters server name, will create the app for that server, then we use them for auth and further things. But while making call to create application getting errorcode 1010 error for specific servers:

one such server is: mastodonapp.uk

Tried creating app with same detail in other servers but worked, not worked in very few servers